# How to make a page look good printed/across multiple browsers

Tags: html, css, printing, cross-browser

I just had about twenty technical interviews for internships and most of my interviewers had printed off my resume. I've noticed some serious inconsistencies in how it turns out in printed form and I'm assuming the culprit is differences in how different browsers "render" html/css.

The two major issues were (common, and not too big of a deal) bullet point size and the (rare, but a huge deal) width of my resume not fitting into one page so a TON of stuff gets thrown into the next line.

My entire resume is 800px wide, has many bullet points, a few borders, and bunch of divs (some of which are floated left so I can have two columns of stuff). Is there a resource that documents things you need to watch out for in making pages that need to look identical across multiple browsers? Is there a way to scale the page when someone's print margins are 3 inches rather than the alternative of ruining the design?

Thanks!

BTW, Here's the lengthy html/css source (I'm not expecting you to go through it here, but more likely copy paste it into notepad and open up the page for yourself).

edit: or see the [jsfiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVPc6/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Andrew Rasmussen</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        * {margin:0;padding:0;color:#000;font-size:1em}
        body {font:11px Verdana;line-height:13px}
        h2 {margin:0.8em 0 0.2em;text-transform:uppercase;font:bold 1.4em verdana;border-bottom:dotted 1px #777}
        h4 {display:inline;padding-right:4px}
        p, ul {margin-bottom:1.4em}
        ul {margin-left:1.2em;padding-left:1.2em;margin-bottom:0}
        li {margin-bottom: .2em}
        #experience h3 {font-weight:normal}
        #title {text-align:center}
        #title p {margin:0}
        #title h1 {font:normal 1.8em verdana}
        #skills {clear:both}
        #skills p {display:inline;margin:none}
        #other h3, #other p {display:inline}
        #wrapper {width:800px}
        .entry {float:left;height:140px;border-bottom:1px dotted black}
        .odd {border-right:1px dotted black;width:394px;padding-right:5px}
        .even {width:390px;padding-left:10px}
        .five {height:125px;border-bottom:none}
        .six {height:125px;border-bottom:none}
        .for {font:bold 1em verdana;position:relative}
        .for span {font-style:oblique;font:normal 1em verdana;position:absolute;right:0;top:0}
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {padding:2em}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="masthead"> 
    <div id="title"><h1>Andrew Rasmussen</h1><p>3A Software Engineering - University of Waterloo</p><p>arasmussen [at] katworks.com</p></div>   
</div>
<div id="skills" class="section">   
    <h2>Technical Skills</h2>
        <ul>
        <li>Eight years of programming experience
        <ul>
            <li><h4>C/C++ (8 years)</h4>- 3D games (OpenGL), industry experience with pointers, STL, OOP, templates</li>
            <li><h4>PHP, MySQL (2 years)</h4>- Backend of web applications with thousands of rows in the database</li>
            <li><h4>OpenGL/GLSL (1 year)</h4>- Modern OpenGL using vertex buffer objects, fragment/vertex shaders</li>
            <li><h4>C# (8 months)</h4>- Windows Forms GUI applications, backend of ASP.NET web applications</li>
            <li><h4>JavaScript, jQuery (6 months)</h4>- Interactive web plugins</li>
            <li><h4>Python (6 months)</h4>- 2D games using PyGame (Astroids and Breakout clones)</li>
        </ul></li>
        <li>Familiarity: XML, JSON, Regex, HTML, CSS, Scheme, ASP.NET, Perl, Lua, Bash</li>
        <li>Platforms: Linux (Ubuntu, Red Hat, Fedora), Windows</li>
        <li>Editors: Vim, Visual Studio 2008/2010, Eclipse</li>
    </ul></div>
<div id="experience" class="section"><h2>Relevant Work Experience</h2>
    <div class="entry odd">
        <div class="for">Digital Extremes: London, ON<span>September-December, 2011</span></div>
        <h3>Star Trek Gameplay Programming</h3>
        <div class="details">
            <ul>
                <li>Independently designed, implemented, and tested many new features and bug fixes</li>
                <li>Touched a broad spectrum of codebase from low-level network serialization in the engine to high-level visible gameplay features</li>
                <li>Technologies: C++, Lua</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry even">
        <div class="for">Morgan Stanley: New York, NY<span>January-April, 2011</span></div>
        <h3>Electronic Trading Infrastructure</h3>
        <div class="details">
            <ul>
                <li>Enhanced and fixed a C++ project which serializes C++ objects into specific formats</li>
                <li>Project was distributed for use in internal trading applications in production</li>
                <li>Solely responsible for the design and testing of my enhancements and bug fixes</li>
                <li>Technologies: C++, Bash, Perl, Python, JSON</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry odd">
        <div class="for">Qualcomm Incorporated: San Diego, CA<span>May-August, 2010</span></div>
        <h3>QDSP6 Audio Test Framework</h3>
        <div class="details">
            <ul>
                <li>Designed and developed a Perl script to automate audio testing with extensive capabilities, including running overnight stress tests, recording audio playback, and comparing audio output using bit exactness</li>
                <li>Ran stability and stress tests for bi-weekly builds</li>
                <li>Assisted our development team in developing these C++ tests</li>
                <li>Technologies: Perl, C++, Bash</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="entry even">
        <div class="for">Microsoft Corporation: Redmond, WA<span>June-August, 2009</span></div>
        <h3>Visual Studio 2010 Globalization</h3>
        <div class="details">
            <ul>
                <li>Developed and tested a web-based Silverlight application that could be localized for multiple locales as a presentation piece to help explain the process of Globalization</li>
                <li>Pseudo-localized a daily build of Visual Studio 2010 for familiarity with the globalization process</li>
                <li>Technologies: ASP.NET, Silverlight, C#, HTML, CSS</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="entry odd five">
        <div class="for">Microsoft Corporation: Redmond, WA<span>June-August, 2008</span></div>
        <h3>Windows Embedded, Point of Service</h3>
        <div class="details">
            <ul>
                <li>Developed an application that kept an inventory of POS devices and associated information</li>
                <li>Designed a neat, systematic, GUI that could be accessed throughout the entire team (over network)</li>
                <li>Technologies: C#, Windows Forms, SQL, ADO.NET</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry even six">
        <div class="for">Freelance Work</div>
        <div class="details">
            <ul>
                <li>Real Estate Listing - currently developing an interactive real estate site (PHP, jQuery, MySQL) - for Tungsten Property</li>
                <li>Content Slider - a jQuery plugin that slides between any generic unordered list of div's you give it - for Katworks Inc.</li>
                <li>Xliff Target Editor - a C# WinForms application to edit XML-like files with a GUI - for Katworks Inc.</li>
                <li>Directory Remover - an easily configurable DOS Batch script to schedule the removal of certain directories - for Global Labs</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="other">    
    <div id="activities" class="section"><h2>Related Activities</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><h3>Game/Graphics Programming:</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>3D games (C++, modern OpenGL) using vertex buffer objects and shaders (GLSL)</li>
                    <li>Rendered ~3 million textured triangles using VBOs with >300fps in a minecraft-like game (including physics)</li>
                    <li>Designed and implemented a game using a heightmap and associated collision detection</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><h3>Web Programming:</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Interactive web plugins using vanilla JavaScript or jQuery</li>
                    <li>Applications with a PHP/MySQL backend and careful, secure, graphical interface to the database</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><h3>Stack Overflow: </h3>Over 130 answers, have a reputation in the top 12% of users; mostly from answering C++/OpenGL questions</li>
            <li><h3>Project Euler: </h3>Completion of the dozens of challenges on this programming challenge/contest site for fun</li>
            <li><h3>UW/Google AI Challenge: </h3>Participation in two Google sponsored, UW hosted, AI programming competitions. Overall ranking in both challenges were in the top quartile. Competition subjects include Rock Paper Scissors and Tron.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div id="education" class="section"><h2>Education</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><h3>Candidate for Bachelor of Software Engineering </h3>at the University of Waterloo, June 2014. Relevant courses include Operating Systems, Algorithms, Object Oriented Software Development, Data Structures</li></ul></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [CSS3 Module: Paged Media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/), where you could define the [margin](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#margin-boxes) and other properties yourself. However, I recommend you to convert your resume into a PDF and put it on your website for offline use, because (1) you can't be sure whether the recipient's browser will understand your stylesheet and (2) whether the font 'Verdana' is installed on the recipients PC.

If you want to achieve the same behavior on *all* browsers your interviewers *could* use, then you'll have to work through dozen of compatibility tests, install several browser, print on different operation systems... Even then you can't be sure your recipient isn't using a browser that behaves in a strange way. HTML and CSS are - after all - only markup/style languages and the *standards* are only *recommendations*. A PDF is determined to look the same on all compatible devices and is an ISO standard. I would rather stick to PDF, than use HTML/CSS for this kind of design you provided.

(Extra information - on decent browser, you can achieve `.odd` `.even` with `.entry:nth-of-type(odd)`, `.entry:nth-of-type(even)`.)

Comment: +1 for suggesting PDF; HTML simply isn't suitable for printing as of today if you care about layout.

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided this information in my post, but I submit my resume to the employers through my school, and they only accept html  formats and their parser will not accept a DOCTYPE (more to Mr Lister than you). Otherwise, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Bullet point size anomalies are caused by quirks mode. Put a DOCTYPE declaration on top to trigger standards mode and the bullets will be OK.

Apart from `margin:none`, I don't really see any errors in your source.
Well, it's recommended to treat font names as case sensitive, so that would be 'Verdana', the way the system has it.

I don't think there's really a comprehensive list of that kind of recommendations somewhere. Maybe I should put up something myself.

Anyway, see the other answer.

Comment: Hey, please see the comment I left on Zeta's post. Thanks for the post.